# Unexpected Error at Installing CS6 on macOS 10.12

Tags: macos, adobe, macos-sierra

I want re-install my licensed CS6 Web & Design Premium os macOS 10.12 Sierra. However, installer says "Could not start the installation. Any file may be missing."

I got the PDapp.log which created by installer in /Libary/Logs.

**The Log:**

```
Wed Oct 12 19:34:00 2016    [INFO] Setup - Build Version - 6.0.335.0
Wed Oct 12 19:34:00 2016    [INFO] Setup - Logging Level verbosity Set  to 4
Wed Oct 12 19:34:00 2016    [INFO] Setup - TimeLog: Bootstrapper Start
Wed Oct 12 19:34:00 2016    [INFO] Setup - TimeLog: Start initial checks
Wed Oct 12 19:34:00 2016    [INFO] Setup - Launch Path set to /var/folders/ln/ljj38hdx5f13q0db1q58bpsr0000gp/T/AppTranslocation/E0C66AE8-34B2-4A80-A424-D031D2709AEA/d
Wed Oct 12 19:34:00 2016    [INFO] Setup - Found 6 packages in setup manifest
Wed Oct 12 19:34:00 2016    [INFO] PIM - Build Version - 6.0.335.0
Wed Oct 12 19:34:00 2016    [INFO] PIM - Logging Level verbosity Set  to 4
Wed Oct 12 19:34:00 2016    [WARN] PIM - Detected Old content in USF trying to delete it...
Wed Oct 12 19:34:00 2016    [WARN] PIM - Successfully deleted old content...
Wed Oct 12 19:34:00 2016    [INFO] PIM - Build Version - 6.0.335.0
Wed Oct 12 19:34:00 2016    [INFO] PIM - Logging Level verbosity Set  to 4
Wed Oct 12 19:34:00 2016    [INFO] PIM - CREATE PIM Instance ...
Wed Oct 12 19:34:00 2016    [INFO] PIM - trying to createOrUpdatePIMDbSchema.
Wed Oct 12 19:34:00 2016    [INFO] PIM - SUCCESS Created Tables.
Wed Oct 12 19:34:00 2016    [INFO] PIM - PIM Database is Up To Date.
Wed Oct 12 19:34:00 2016    [INFO] PIM - Updater Inventory location:/var/folders/ln/ljj38hdx5f13q0db1q58bpsr0000gp/T/AppTranslocation/E0C66AE8-34B2-4A80-A424-D031D2709AEA/d/Install.app/Contents/Frameworks/UpdaterInventory.framework/UpdaterInventory
Wed Oct 12 19:34:00 2016    [FATAL] PIM - ERROR invalid xml file path. Could not read data from path /var/folders/ln/ljj38hdx5f13q0db1q58bpsr0000gp/T/AppTranslocation/E0C66AE8-34B2-4A80-A424-D031D2709AEA/d/packages/core/PDApp.pimx
Wed Oct 12 19:34:00 2016    [FATAL] PIM - Error Description Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “PDApp.pimx” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/var/folders/ln/ljj38hdx5f13q0db1q58bpsr0000gp/T/AppTranslocation/E0C66AE8-34B2-4A80-A424-D031D2709AEA/d/packages/core/PDApp.pimx, NSUnderlyingError=0x23add0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
Wed Oct 12 19:34:00 2016    [ERROR] PIM - Error couldnot initialize XML. Improper xml file.
Wed Oct 12 19:34:00 2016    [ERROR] Setup - Error in initialization. Manifest parsing failed.
Wed Oct 12 19:34:00 2016    [INFO] Setup - TimeLog: End initial checks
Wed Oct 12 19:34:02 2016    [INFO] Setup - =================  Exiting Installer with Code: 0  =================
Wed Oct 12 19:34:02 2016    [INFO] PIM - PIMSqlite closeDB status 0 
Wed Oct 12 19:34:02 2016    [INFO] PIM - FREE PIM Instance ...
```

How can I fix this error?

Thanks.

Comment: Try http://apple.stackexchange.com, not stackoverflow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For OSX 10.12.X (Sierra) run installer directly from Install.app/Contents/MacOS/Install